# mock object for document element

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have next test code:

```
it("Test", function() {
    loadResources();

    expect(document.getElementById('MyElement').innerHTML).toBe("my string");
});
```

Body of function **loadResources()**:

```
document.getElementById('MyElement').innerHTML = "my string";
```

My test fails with following message:

> TypeError: Cannot set property "innerHTML" of null.

Looks like I need to create mock object for innerHTML. How I can do this?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I think you should mock `getElementById` to return a dummy HTMLElement

**JASMINE V1.3 OR BELOW**

```
var dummyElement = document.createElement('div');
document.getElementById = jasmine.createSpy('HTML Element').andReturn(dummyElement);
```

**JASMINE V2.0+**

```
var dummyElement = document.createElement('div');
document.getElementById = jasmine.createSpy('HTML Element').and.returnValue(dummyElement);
```

So now, for every call to `document.getElementById` it will return the dummy element. It will set the dummy element's innerHTML and compare it to the expected result in the end.

EDIT: And I guess you should replace `toBe` with `toEqual`. `toBe` might fail because it will test for object identity instead of value equality.

EDIT2 (regarding multiple ID): I am not sure, but you could call a fake instead. It will create a new HTML element for each ID (if it doesn't exist yet) and store it in an object literal for future use (i.e. other calls to `getElementById` with same ID)

**JASMINE V1.3 OR BELOW**

```js
var HTMLElements = {};
document.getElementById = jasmine.createSpy('HTML Element').andCallFake(function(ID) {
   if(!HTMLElements[ID]) {
      var newElement = document.createElement('div');
      HTMLElements[ID] = newElement;
   }
   return HTMLElements[ID];
});
```

**JASMINE V2.0+**

```js
var HTMLElements = {};
document.getElementById = jasmine.createSpy('HTML Element').and.callFake(function(ID) {
   if(!HTMLElements[ID]) {
      var newElement = document.createElement('div');
      HTMLElements[ID] = newElement;
   }
   return HTMLElements[ID];
});
```

Comment: What if I have 2 id's?
document.getElementById('MyElement1').innerHTML = "my string";
document.getElementById('MyElement2').innerHTML = "my string";

And I need to check these id's?

Comment: Note that this answer has used jasmine 1.3 syntax. jasmine 2.0 (and after) is different. For example: jasmine.createSpy('HTML Element').and.returnValue(dummyElement);

Comment: @devnull69 Could you clarify that 'HTML Element' from your examples is supposed to be the ID one would normally pass to document.getElementById?

Comment: No, `ID` is this ID you are talking about, `HTML Element` is just a string name of the spy

Comment: Should that be .and.callFake?

Comment: This is a really useful answer. It can make testing some of those harder to reach pieces of code much easier. Thank you!

Comment: For a popular Github reference: https://github.com/dikshantdesai7/PBPApps/blob/c8f66c8747b1993cc814a1bd1657b7aee9b7f603/pbp/apps/ui/pbp_ui/src/app/modules/report/report-item/report-item.component.spec.ts

Comment: is it resetable if I do that? because It might somehow interfere with the other spec files since document is a global object

Answer (score 7):

Set up a document body and getElement by id. I'm using jest and this works fine.
Check out this [example from jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-jquery).

```
test('Toggle innerHtml of an element', () =>{
document.body.innerHTML =
            '<div>' +
            '  <div id="username" >Hello</div>' +
            '  <button id="button" />' +
            '</div>';
var el = document.getElementById('username');
var newText = 'new inner text';
el.innerText = newText;
expect(el.innerText).toEqual(newText);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
it('should blah', () => {
  const elementMock = {
    innerHTML: 'my string'
  };    

  loadResources();

  jasmine.spyOn(document, 'getElementById').and.returnValue(elementMock);

  expect(document.getElementById('MyElement').innerHTML).toBe('my string');
});
```