# How to unset spy on document.getElementById created using jasmine.createSpy

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

```
document.getElementById = jasmine.createSpy('HTMLElement').and.returnValue(null);
```

I am creating a spy to make `document.getElementById` return the required element in of one my tests. Due to document being global, this spy lives across the spec files. Is there a way to remove this spy and revert the `getElementById` to it's original implementation after the test executes?

Note: I am using new version of Jasmine and Karma which executes the unit test randomly (Random test execution is required). I am required to spy on getElementById in multiple spec files. If I set the return value to null in one of the test then even after resetting it to return valid dom element in other test, still it returns null in other test as well due to new random feature of Karma.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you will need to use a different method to spy on `document.getElementById`.

Jasmine automatically removes spies created with methods like `spyOn()` ([source](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/236#issuecomment-28958973)).

So just change your code to:

```js
spyOn(document, 'getElementById').and.returnValue(null);
```

and it should automatically remove the spy once the test completes.

Comment: spyOn document doesn't work.
check this link for possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495325/mock-object-for-document-element

Answer (score 0):

**Reset single spy call**

```
spyOn(object, 'method');
expect(object.method).toHaveBeenCalled();
object.method.calls.reset();
```

**Reset all spy calls**

If you would like to reset all spy calls, then use:

```
spy.calls.reset()
```

Here is the documentation for it: https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.6/Spy_calls.html

Comment: spy.calls.reset() will just reset the spy, but the spy will still exist. I want to remove it right after it was used.