# Jasmine Karma afterall hides property error

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am running ng test and getting the following error

> An error was thrown in afterAll
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hide')
> at SafeSubscriber._next (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/src/app/admin/admin-appdetails/admin-appdetails.component.ts:676:8)
> at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Subscriber.js:183:1)
> at SafeSubscriber.next (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Subscriber.js:122:1)
> at Subscriber._next (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Subscriber.js:72:1)
> at Subscriber.next (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Subscriber.js:49:1)    at Observable._subscribe (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/util/subscribeToArray.js:3:1)
> at Observable._trySubscribe (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Observable.js:42:1)
> at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Observable.js:28:1)
> at AdminAppdetailsComponent.onBlockUnblockStatus (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/src/app/admin/admin-appdetails/admin-appdetails.component.ts:673:8)
> at UserContext. (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/src/app/admin/admin-appdetails/admin-appdetailsChrome 104.0.5112.81 (Windows 10) ERROR
> An error was thrown in afterAll
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hide')
> at SafeSubscriber._next (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/src/app/admin/admin-appdetails/admin-appdetails.component.ts:676:8)
> at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Subscriber.js:183:1)
> at SafeSubscriber.next (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Subscriber.js:122:1)

```
**admin-appdetails.component.ts**
```

https://wtools.io/paste-code/bEu3

**admin-appdetails.components.spec.ts**
https://wtools.io/paste-code/bEu4

These are the files

Unable to detect why this error is coming.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the stacktrace, you can clearly see the problem is in `admin-appdetails.component.ts:676:8` check for the hide property and fix it!

```
An error was thrown in afterAll TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hide') at SafeSubscriber._next (http://localhost:9876/karma_webpack/webpack:/src/app/admin/admin-appdetails/admin-appdetails.component.ts:676:8) at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub
```

Mock the property in all test cases and it worked.

Comment: component.modalRef = {
      content: null,
      (676 line) hide: () => {
      },
      setClass: () => {
      }
      };

Comment: @dhS please share the entire test case? I need more inputs to fix it, else you can debug from your side!

Comment: @dhS I think you need to create a mock function for `hid()` and `setClass()` to execute your real code in unit test case

Comment: @NarenMurali i have attached the code and unable to detect what to change.

Comment: @dhS the problem is coming from `this.modalRef.hide();` so in all the test cases of functions that use this line, you need to  add a dummy object like `component.modalRef = { hide: () => {}}`

Comment: @dhS try it, sorry this is a tough one to solve, all the best :)

Comment: @NarenMurali do you how to mock this const approveForm = <HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById('approveForm'); in test case

Comment: @dhS Generally [`how to mock document`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495325/mock-object-for-document-element)